# How to remove duplicate letters while preserving the smallest lexicographical order

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have a task to remove duplicates from given string (classic interview question), but this one is a bit different, the end result should be in the smallest lexicographical order possible among other. For example, `cbacdcbc => acdb, bcabc => abc`. I saw several related problems in SO, but I could not find the answer.

**Edit**: Here is my code so far (not working properly):

```
public static String removeDuplicateCharsAlphbetically(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    if (len<2) return str;

    char[] letters = str.toCharArray();
    int[] counts = new int[26];
    for (char c : letters) {
        counts[c-97]++;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
        if (letters[i]==letters[i+1]) continue;

        if (counts[letters[i]-97]==1) {
            sb.append(letters[i]);
        } else if (counts[letters[i]-97] != 0) {
            if (letters[i]<letters[i+1] && counts[letters[i]-97] == 1) {
                sb.append(letters[i]);
                counts[letters[i]-97]=0;
            } else {
                counts[letters[i]-97]--;
            } 
        }

    }

    return sb.toString();
 }
```

**EDIT2**: I am sorry for not putting link of the question earlier. here is the [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicate-letters/description/):

Comment: why is `Python` tagged?

Comment: I need solution in either Python or Java

Comment: and what do you mean by *smallest* lexicographical order? There is **only one** lexicographical order.. Why does `'c'` come before `'b'` in your first example?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Are you sure? https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicate-letters/description/

Comment: @Humyun It says *"...the smallest **in** lexicographical order..."*. I still don't get why `'c'` come before `'b'`. Do you understand the question to begin with?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis because after 'c' there is 'd' which is bigger than 'c', so even c is bigger than 'b'  it is smaller than 'd'. So you should keep it before 'd'

Comment: @Humoyun Can't you just remove the duplicates and perform a sort after that?

Comment: @user3437460 bac should stay bac, not abc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's create a set of all distinct letters of the string `s`. The size of this set is the length of the answer and the number of steps in our algorithm. 
We will add one letter to the answer on each step with the following greedy approach:

On every step iterate through the remaining letters in alphabetical order and for every letter `l`:

1. Find the first occurrence of `l` in `s`. Let's name it `lpos`.
2. If the substring `s[lpos, end]` contains all remaining letters then add `l` to the result, replace `s` with `s[lpos+1, end]` and go to the next step with reduced remaining letters set.

Implementation with some optimizations to achieve better time complexity:

```
public String removeDuplicateLetters(String s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int[] subsets = new int[s.length()];

    int subset = 0;
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        subset = addToSet(subset, ch);
        subsets[i] = subset;
    }

    int curPos = 0;
    while (subset != 0) {
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) {
            if (inSet(subset, ch)) {
                int chPos = s.indexOf(ch, curPos);
                if (includes(subsets[chPos], subset)) {
                    result.append(ch);
                    subset = removeFromSet(subset, ch);
                    curPos = chPos + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result.toString(); 
}   

private boolean inSet(int set, char ch) {
    return (set & (1 << (ch - 'a'))) != 0;    
}

private boolean includes(int set, int subset) {
    return (set | subset) == set;
}

private int addToSet(int set, char ch) {
    return set | (1 << (ch - 'a'));
}

private int removeFromSet(int set, char ch) {
    return set & ~(1 << (ch - 'a')); 
}
```

Runnable version: https://ideone.com/wIKi3x

Comment: thank you very much for time and effort you spent on solution

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in O(StringLenght) time.
String lenght = N;
Time Complexity  O(N) , single scan of the string.
Space Complexity O(26)

Solution:

1. Create an array of Alphabet letters which will store pointer to doubly link list  Node .

`ListNode* array[26]; // Initialized with NULL value.`

2. Create an empty linkedlist , which will represent the solution string at any point of time, in reverse order.
3. Scan the string and for each letter , check the letter ,ltr, check `array[ltr-'a']`
   .... a.) if it is NULL , it means , it is first occurence and add it to the linked list .     ... b.) If array is pointing to any node listNodeltr , it means letter is already in result
   i. check  value for previous listNode to  listNodeltr, in linklist ,

If value of `listNodeltr->prev->val < listNode->val` , it means removing the current node from this position will make the result lexographically smaller .
So remove listNodeLtr from the current postion in linkedList and add it to the end.

```
Else, current postion of ltr is find and continue.
```

**cba**cdcbc

[a]->[b]->[c]

**cbac**dcbc
[c]->[a]->[b]

**cbacdc**bc
[d]->[c]->[a]->[b]

**cbacdcb**c
[b]->[d]->[c]->[a]

**cbacdcbc**
[b]->[d]->[c]->[a]

print linklist in reverse order : acdb.

Answer (score 3):

Build the result by going backwards from end of the input to start. On each step:

1. If new letter is encountered, prepend it to result.
2. If duplicate is encountered, then compare it with the head of result. If head is greater, remove duplicate from the result and prepend it instead.

`LinkedHashSet` is good both for storing result set and its internal order.

```
public static String unduplicate(String input) {
    Character head = null;
    Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        Character c = input.charAt(i);
        if (set.add(c))
            head = c;
        else if (c.compareTo(head) < 0) {
            set.remove(c);
            set.add(head = c);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(set.size());
    for (Character c: set)
        result.append(c);
    return result.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but seems to be wrong. Test: `abacb`, answer: `abc`. This algorithm returns `acb`

Answer (score 2):

Observation 1: the first letter of the output is the least letter such that all other letters appear to the right of its leftmost appearance in the string.

Observation 2: the remaining letters of the output are a subsequence of the letters to the right of the leftmost appearance of the first letter.

This suggests a recursive algorithm.

```
def rem_dups_lex_least(s):
    if not s:
        return ''
    n = len(set(s))  # number of distinct letters in s
    seen = set()     # number of distinct letters seen while scanning right to left
    for j in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):  # len(s)-1 down to 0
        seen.add(s[j])
        if len(seen) == n:  # all letters seen
            first = min(s[:j+1])
            i = s.index(first)  # leftmost appearance
            return first + rem_dups_lex_least(''.join(c for c in s[i+1:] if c != first))
```